# Open Source Webinar Software

Tags: gratis, linux, open-source, video-conferencing

Is anyone aware of open source webinar/webcasting/webconferencing software that meets the following criteria?

- Allows you to stream video and pre-made video files
- Has moderated sessions and attendees can ask questions, which we can then answer.
- Clean, non-clunky UI (or at least one we can modify in order to clean up)
- Preferably, we should be able to set up this software on Linux in the AWS cloud or at least stream through AWS.

I've been looking around Google for one that meets these criteria but haven't found one yet. Any suggestions?